# Font visual rendering different on safari. Working fine on chrome

Tags: html, css

Footer text visual not looking same at Safari. Working fine on chrome. I have applied many hacks to fix issue but no luck.

Attached image of issue with difference in safari and chrome:

http://prntscr.com/g5t8kg

Comment: You will need to post a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)** so that we can help you with your code.

Comment: I can't add code example.. Its just real time. That's why i shared live website link.

Comment: Using google font for Open Sans? Why you use `'open_sansregular'`

Comment: @Toastrackenigma  I have updated image with clear issue difference

Comment: @xaid i can't use online fonts api due to project requirements. That issue is working fine on inner pages on footer. Just wrong on home page ( safari )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's may be help to you, just add this code in your css, it's safari hack code

```
::i-block-chrome, footer .address, .address a {
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you